# I cant seem to understand how to restrict my scanf to only numbers of float

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define mL 5
    #define NL 20
    #define UL 6



    struct LIST
    {
        char n[NL];
        float am;
        char u[UL];
    };
    struct array
    {
        struct LIST array;
    };


    void addCityInformation(struct array *add, int *items);
    void printCities(struct array *all, int items);
    int main(void)
    {
        struct array shopping[mL];
        int choice, nrOfItemsAdded = 0;

        do
        {
            printf("\nWhat du you want to do?");
            printf("\n1 - add grocery");
            printf("\n2 - print shopping list");
            printf("\n3 - exit");
            printf("\nYour choice: ");
            scanf("%d", &choice);
            while(getchar() != '\n');

            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:
                addCityInformation(&shopping[nrOfItemsAdded], &nrOfItemsAdded);
                break;
            case 2:
                printCities(shopping, nrOfItemsAdded);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Exiting program\n\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid input\n\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        while(choice != 3);
        return 0;
    }

     int clean_stdin()
{
    while (getchar()!='\n');

}

    void addCityInformation(struct array *add, int *items)
    {

        if(*items == mL)
            printf("No more space in the list\n");
        else
        {
            printf("Enter name: ");
            fgets(add->array.n, NL, stdin);
            add->array.n[strlen(add->array.n)-1] = '\0';
            do {

        printf("Enter amount: ");
        }while (scanf("%f", &add->array.am )); //loop untill other than float 
            getchar();
            printf("Enter unit: ");
            fgets((add->array.u), UL, stdin);
            add->array.u[strlen(add->array.u)-1] = '\0';
            (*items)++;
        }
    }

    void printCities(struct array *all, int items)
    {

        printf("\n\n%-20s %-15s %-9s | %-6s\n", "Name", "amount", "unit");
        printf("--------------------------------------------------------\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < items; i++)

            printf("%-20s %-15.1f %-9.4s \n", all[i].array.n, all[i].array.am, all[i].array.u);

    }
```

This is my loop beside that i am only showing a part of the code. It now just continues to give enter amount and letting me register it in the struct. I want to restrict the user to only entering positive numbers and no character at all. And if he types a character it should rerun the loop even if it is 123Av123 it should run the loop and only register the correct number

Edit: now showing the whole code//loop untill other than float is what i want help with

Comment: The starting point is that `scanf` should return exactly `1` in this example. This indicates it successfully scanned `1` value.

Comment: use `fgets()` for user input. `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin); /* error checking ommited */ if (sscanf(buf, "%f", &floatvar) != 1) /* error */;`

Comment: use `fgets()` for user input. `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin); /* error checking ommited */ floatvar = strtod(buf, 0); /* errno checking ommited */`

Comment: OT: regarding: `#define mL 5
    #define NL 20
    #define UL 6`   1) spell things out, don't use obscure abbreviations  2) it is 'typical' for `#define` names to be all CAPS with underscores to separate individual words

Comment: OT:  although the compiler can (usually) determine what you mean by: `struct array
    {
        struct LIST array;
    };`  where `array` is both the struct name and the name of a field within the struct, Us humans have a difficult time when we see `array` within the code

Comment: I undestand that posted the whole code just to make it eazier for others to undestand the problem I make sure to name everything when I am coding for something this just a test code that I want to solve some problem with

Comment: regarding: `printf("\n\n%-20s %-15s %-9s | %-6s\n", "Name", "amount", "unit");`   This has 4 output format specifiers, but only 3 fields to output.  This is an error, please correct

Comment: sure fixed that, but I am still not able to fix my starting problem to only let users enter number and not characters

Comment: OT:  regarding: `while(getchar() != '\n');`  Should also check for EOF`

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("\nWhat du you want to do?");
            printf("\n1 - add grocery");
            printf("\n2 - print shopping list");
            printf("\n3 - exit");
            printf("\nYour choice: ");`  The function: `printf()` is rather expensive in CPU cycles,  Suggest something similar to: `printf("\nWhat du you want to do?" newline
            "\n1 - add grocery" newline
            "\n2 - print shopping list" newline
            "\n3 - exit" newline
            "\nYour choice: ");`  where `newline` is a carriage return while editing the code

Comment: regarding: `{
    while (getchar()!='\n');

}`  the opening brace '{' should not be there.

Comment: for calls to `printf()` with no formatting nor parameters, suggest using: `puts()`

Comment: regarding: `}while (scanf("%f", &add->array.am ));`  scanf()` can return EOF (-1) which would put this `do...while` loop into a forever condition.  Suggest: `} while( scanf("%f", &add->array.am ) == 1 ) );`

Comment: regarding: `add->array.n[strlen(add->array.n)-1] = '\0';`  This only works if `fgets()` actually input a newline.  Suggest: `add->array.n[ strspn( add->array.n, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`  as this will only change an existing NUL byte if no `'\n'` was input

Comment: All helpful comments but I am still stuck at the loop problem do you have some time to type in discord ?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by: `time to type in discord`.

Comment: the posted code contains  logic problem.   What happens if the user enters less than `mL` city entries before entering: `2` to request a list of the information?

Comment: ok but someplace to chat where i can ask you questions

Comment: the problem states that it is ok to do so because we are working with fixed amount of memory

Comment: Suggestion:  read the line from the user into a buffer, then use `strtof` (or similar) to obtain the value the user entered as that function does set an error indication when a problem occurs

Comment: since the admin has again modified the user interface for stackoverflow.com,  I do not know how to create a chat room

Comment: would you be able to show me an example of using strtof in my problem because i am kinda lost like in the do while enter amount line -would really appreciate it

Comment: if the user types characters when they should have been typing integers, then, for the code to continue the code needs to consume those characters

Answer (score 1):

```
int check=scanf("%f", &add->array.am )
if(check!=1||add->array.am<0){
printf("Incorrect input");
return 1;
}
```

I think that will do it.
Edit: you wanted it to rerun after so use `continue;` instead of `return;`

Comment: Would you do this still with the code that I just posted ?